# The mathematics behind Sobol sequences

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, finite-fields, random

I am using Sobol sequence as random number generator in a computer program.

Beyond just making the program work, I would like to learn the mathematics behind the Sobol sequence (and other quasi-random sequences).

I understand that the Sobol sequence is based on finite field, but I have not found any introductory finite field book with applications on quasi-random sequence.

May I ask for some related book/links on this specific topic?

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobol_sequence) offering enough pointers?